# Why is it disallowed to convert from VirtualBase::* to Derived::*?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance, member-pointers

Yesterday, me and my colleague weren't sure why the language forbids this conversion

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B : virtual A { };

int A::*p = &A::x;
int B::*pb = p;
```

Not even a cast helps. Why does the Standard not support converting a base member pointer to a derived member pointer if the base member pointer is a virtual base class?

Relevant C++ standard reference:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of `B` of type cv `T`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to member of `D` of type cv `T`”, where `D` is a derived class (Clause 10) of `B`. If `B` is an inaccessible (Clause 11), ambiguous (10.2), or virtual (10.1) base class of `D`, or a base class of a virtual base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed.

Both function and data member pointers are affected.

Comment: Great question! Look forward to hearing the answer.

Comment: Following discussion with TemplateRex, could this question be simplified to "why can't I do `int B::*pb = &B::x;`? It's not just that you can't convert `p`: you can't have a pointer-to-member to a member in a virtual base at all.

Comment: @steve my code is doing the same as yours. Just that it uses a temporary variable to add clarity. Your code is attempting to do the conversion aswell.

Comment: @steve it is not correct that you cant have such a member pointer: "p" in my code is such a member pointer.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `p` has type `int A::*`. The pointer itself doesn't need to "know" whether `A` is a virtual base of anything, since it is only ever dereferened by code that can figure out the `A` base class sub-object address before applying it. In order to have a pointer of type `int B::*` that referred to `x`, the pointer value would have to indicate that the required member is in `A`. That is the distinction I mean to draw by saying that you cannot have a pointer-to-member to a member in a base class.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: but you're right, my example code does obscure my point because `&B::x;` has type `int A::*`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I considered to word the question like that, but am in the opinion that it wouldn't be as clear. Something like "Can a member pointer C::* exist whose value refers to a member of a virtual base class" would not encapsulate the original issue my colleague and me had (which was the conversion). Hence I stated it using the conversion.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: OK, if that's how you see it :-). It's just that after the discussion with TemplateRex I came to the conclusion that the answer to your question, "why can't I do this conversion?" is "because the thing you're trying to convert to doesn't exist". Which immediately raises the new question, "why doesn't it exist?"!

Comment: @SteveJessop well the answer to why it doesn't exist would be the answer to my question. Saying that it is because the type doesn't exist isn't a real answer. Alternatively, if I stated the question "why can't I have a value of this type?" you could have said "because there is no conversion from the value &A::x up to B::*" as an "answer"-in-disguise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lippman's "[**Inside the C++ Object model**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545)" has a discussion about this:

> [there] is the need to make the virtual base class location within
>   each derived class object available  at runtime. For example, in the
>   following program fragment:

```
class X { public: int i; }; 
class A : public virtual X { public: int j; }; 
class B : public virtual X { public: double d; }; 
class C : public A, public B { public: int k; }; 
// cannot resolve location of pa->X::i at compile-time 
void foo( const A* pa ) { pa->i = 1024; } 

main() { 
 foo( new A ); 
 foo( new C ); 
 // ... 
}
```

> the compiler cannot fix the physical offset of `X::i` accessed through
>   `pa` within `foo()`, since the actual type  of `pa` can vary with each of
>   `foo()`'s invocations. Rather, the compiler must transform the code
>   doing the  access so that the resolution of `X::i` can be delayed until
>   runtime.

Essentially, **the presence of a virtual base class invalidates bitwise copy 
semantics**.

Comment: But aren't class members ordered by inheritance in the memory? eg. `[X members][A or B members][C members]`. In such case trying to access X::sth (theoretically) should be deterministic regardless of what the object actually is.

Comment: @Spook the point is that the compiler needs flexibility because `A: virtual X` could be combined with `B : virtual X` into a `C : A, B`. Short of whole-program analysis, a fixed layout will run afoul very soon. Lippman has a quote: "Virtual base class support wanders off into the Byzantine".

Comment: Why can't the compiler do the same "lets get the precise offset at runtime" with the member pointer?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I am not sure, perhaps the combinations of class taking `virtual` base classes, with `virtual` functions present in each are just too complicated to work out subobject-layouts reliably. At least compiler vendors thought so when the Standard was set into stone (the Lippman book is from 1996).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb btw, maybe `dynamic_cast` could be made to work with a Sufficiently Smart Compiler? It would not be free, because virtual base classes can add extra levels of indirection to trace the offsets.

Comment: I agree with Johannes, it "feels like" some kind of cast should be able to do this. The information encapsulated in the value of `p` is, "offset 0". The information encapsulated in the type of `p` is "apply the offset from the address of an `A`". So there should be some means of taking those two facts and turning them into an `int B::*` that means, "the data member at offset 0 of the A base-class subobject, wherever that may be". Which I would think could then be dereferenced using the same virtual mechanism that dereferences `ptr->x` where `ptr` is a `B*`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think the difficulty is that `p->mem1` and `p->mem2` can resolve to different offsets if `mem1` and `mem2` are inherited from different sub-objects. This means that, yes, you can resolve them at runtime, but, no, there is no cast to a single pointer *without knowing which member you want to access*.

Comment: @TemplateRex: ah, gotcha. So the issue is that pointers-to-member are not required to be sufficiently complex to "record" which virtual base the member belongs to, whereas `ptr->x` knows that statically from the type of `ptr`. So you can't do the conversion for the same reason you can't do `int B::*pb = &B::a;`.

Comment: @SteveJessop I don't think pointers-to-member *could be* sufficiently complex to record whether they belong to the most-derived virtual base , since that is determined by their open set of subclasses. That is what's making the casting impossible.

Comment: @TemplateRex: well, I suppose it would require some kind of type identifier under the covers. In principle I think the `int B::*` could contain some identifier to represent `A`(perhaps only in the context of `B`, not necessarily a global type id), and the vtable of `B` and each of its derived classes could contain a means of determining the `A` base class subobject pointer using that identifier. Which I'm prepared to accept is one step too far to be part of the language.

Comment: @SteveJessop but suppose a Sufficiently Advanced Compiler would do that for a given hierarchy. Then add one diamond level extra, but with the order of derivation reversed. The meaning of "most-derived" (which determines the offsets into the various sub-objects) would then be different and casting two-levels down to the already casted pointer would behave inconsistenly.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**:

I believe a compiler could make conversion from `Base::*` to `Derived::*` possible even when `Derived` derives virtually from `Base`. For this to work a pointer to member would need to record more than just the offset. It would also need to record the type of the original pointer through some type-erasure mechanism.

So my speculation is that the committee thought that this would be too much for a feature that is rarely used. In addition, something similar can be achieved with a pure library feature. (See the long answer.)

**Long answer**:

I hope my argument is not flawed in some corner case but here we go.

Essentially a pointer to member records the offset of the member with respect to the beginning of the class. Consider:

```
struct A { int x; };
struct B : virtual A { int y; };
struct C : B { int z; };

void print_offset(const B& obj) {
  std::cout << (char*) &obj.x - (char*) &obj << '\n';
}

print_offset(B{});
print_offset(C{});
```

On my platform the output is `12` and `16`. This shows that the offset of `a` with respect to `obj`'s address depends on `obj`'s dynamic type: `12` if the dynamic type is `B` and `16` if it's `C`.

Now consider the OP's example:

```
int A::*p = &A::x;
int B::*pb = p;
```

As we saw, for an object of static type `B`, the offset depends on its dynamic type and in the two lines above no object of type `B` is used so there's no dynamic type to get the offset from.

However, to dereference a pointer to member an object is required. Couldn't a compiler take the object used at that time to get the correct offset? Or, in other words, could the offset computation be delayed until the time we evaluate `obj.*pb` (where `obj` is of static type `B`)?

It seems to me that this is possible. It's enough to cast `obj` to `A&` and use the offset recorded in `pb` (which it read from `p`) to get a reference to `obj.x`. For this to work `pb` must "remember" that it was initialized from an `int A::*`.

Here is a draft of template class `ptr_to_member` that implements this strategy. The specialization `ptr_to_member<T, U>` is supposed to work similarly to `T U::*`. (Notice this is just a draft that can be improved in different ways.)

```
template <typename Member, typename Object>
class ptr_to_member {

  Member Object::* p_;
  Member& (ptr_to_member::*dereference_)(Object&) const;

  template <typename Base>
  Member& do_dereference(Object& obj) const {
      auto& base = static_cast<Base&>(obj);
      auto  p    = reinterpret_cast<Member Base::*>(p_);
      return base.*p;
  }

public:

  ptr_to_member(Member Object::*p) :
    p_(p),
    dereference_(&ptr_to_member::do_dereference<Object>) {
  }

  template <typename M, typename O>
  friend class ptr_to_member;

  template <typename Base>
  ptr_to_member(const ptr_to_member<Member, Base>& p) :
    p_(reinterpret_cast<Member Object::*>(p.p_)),
    dereference_(&ptr_to_member::do_dereference<Base>) {
  }

  // Unfortunately, we can't overload operator .* so we provide this method...
  Member& dereference(Object& obj) const {
    return (this->*dereference_)(obj);
  }

  // ...and this one
  const Member& dereference(const Object& obj) const {
    return dereference(const_cast<Object&>(obj));
  }
};
```

Here is how it should be used:

```
A a;
ptr_to_member<int, A> pa = &A::x; // int A::* pa = &::x
pa.dereference(a) = 42;           // a.*pa = 42;
assert(a.x == 42);

B b;
ptr_to_member<int, B> pb = pa;   // int B::* pb = pa;
pb.dereference(b) = 43;          // b*.pb = 43;
assert(b.x == 43);

C c;
ptr_to_member<int, B> pc = pa;   // int B::* pc = pa;
pc.dereference(c) = 44;          // c.*pd = 44;
assert(c.x == 44);
```

Unfortunately, `ptr_to_member` alone doesn't solve the issue raised by [Steve Jessop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop):

> > Following discussion with TemplateRex, could this question be simplified to "why can't I do int B::*pb = &B::x;? It's not just that you can't convert p: you can't have a pointer-to-member to a member in a virtual base at all.

The reason is that the expression `&B::x` is supposed to record only the offset of `x` from the beginning of `B` which is unkown as we have seen. To make this work, after realising that `B::x` is actually a member of the virtual base `A`, the compiler would need to create something similar to `ptr_to_member<int, B>` from `&A::X` which "remembers" the `A` seen at construction time and records the offset of `x` from the beginning of `A`.

Comment: Nice. Is the `reinterpret_cast` legitimate? I don't think it fundamentally matters if it isn't, since you could come up with another means of type erasure if needed.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think it is: In the constructor it casts from `Member Base::*` to `Member Object::*`. The result is stored in `p_`. `dereference_` (the only user of `p_`) is set to `do_dereference<Base>` which casts `p_` back to the original type. AFAIK this is OK by 5.2.10/9 second bullet point: "converting an rvalue of type “pointer to data member of X of type T1” to the type “pointer to data member of Y of type T2” (where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value." Here `T1 = T2 = Member`.